# How to convert into set data structure a particular property

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I have an array like

```
let x1=[{"data":"hello","id":2},{"data":"hellr","id":17},{"data":"hellr","id":24}]
```

It is a sample array.The array is huge what i want is to convert it into set on property data.Is there a way to do this so that I can remove duplicate of data?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove duplicates from an array of objects in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218999/remove-duplicates-from-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript)

Comment: Does my answer work for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the result from `Array#map` to the `Set` constructor to find all the unique `data` values.

```js
let x1=[{"data":"hello","id":2},{"data":"hellr","id":17},{"data":"hellr","id":24}];
const set = new Set(x1.map(({data})=>data));
console.log([...set]);
```

If you need the objects themselves, you can use `Array#filter` while adding to a `Set`.

```js
let x1=[{"data":"hello","id":2},{"data":"hellr","id":17},{"data":"hellr","id":24}];
const set = new Set;
const res = x1.filter(({data})=>!set.has(data) && set.add(data));
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is fast and draft way

```
let x2 = new Set(
  x1.map(({ data }) => {
    return data
  })
)
```

Comment: Instead of just simply stating that it's a "fast and draft way", an additional *explanation* on the code you've provided will be more *beneficial* to others who view your code.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I'm not understanding your question correctly, but if you want to remove duplicate objects with the same `data` values in your array, you can do this

```
let x1 = [{"data":"hello","id":2},{"data":"hellr","id":17},{"data":"hellr","id":24}];

x1 = x1.filter((item, index, self) => self.findIndex(i => i.data === item.data) === index);
```

Comment: let sortByProperty = function (property) {
    return function (x, y) {
        return ((x[property] === y[property]) ? 0 : ((x[property] > y[property]) ? 1 : -1));
    };
} finalArray=(finalArray.sort(sortByProperty('label'))) // Now I am getting Sorting of the form Data in alphabetical order "A followed by B followed by C so on and then a b c so on but what i want is A followed by a B followed by C followed by c and so on. Could you help me in that?

Comment: I believe this is a different question and you should create a new post for this, but if you want to sort an array of objects by a property value, you can do `x1.sort((a,b) => (a.data > b.data) ? 1 : ((b.data > a.data) ? -1 : 0));`

Comment: [ { data: 'Ellr', id: 17 },
  { data: 'Hello', id: 2 },
  { data: 'ellr', id: 24 },
  { data: 'hello', id: 2 } ] Using Your function i achieved this but what I want is [ { data: 'Ellr', id: 17 },
  { data: 'ellr', id: 2 },
  { data: 'Hello', id: 24 },
  { data: 'hello', id: 2 } ]

Comment: If you want to perform case insensitive comparison, simply convert them into lowercase with `toLowerCase()` like this `x1.sort((a,b) => (a.data.toLowerCase() > b.data.toLowerCase()) ? 1 : ((b.data.toLowerCase() > a.data.toLowerCase()) ? -1 : 0));`

Comment: But Requirement is to maintain exact case in my final Result

Comment: The usage of `toLowerCase()` in the function above is just for sorting purpose, the final output retains the case. Do give it a try.